# PHP new user automatic sign in

Tags: php, oop, authentication, login-script

I've been playing around with login systems and I've got a pretty good (basic, but good) one built. One thing that I just can't seem to get to work is to have a registered user be logged in automatically after submitting the registration form (and the user being inserted, obviously).

Here is my attempt:

*Edit: Added full class, login.tpl.php, and myProfile.php. I apologize for all of the code snippets!

login class:

```
<?php
class login
{
    protected $_email;
    protected $_password;
    protected $hash;

    protected $_db;
    protected $_user;   

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
        $query->execute(array($this->_email));

        if ($query->rowcount() > 0)
        {
                $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if (password_verify ($this->_password , $user['password']))
                {
                    return $user;
                }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->_email = $email;
        $this-> _password = $password;

        $user = $this->validate();
        if ($user)
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            return $user['id'];
        }
        return false;
    }   

    public function createUser($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password)
    {
        $this->hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $query = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name)");
        $query->execute(array(
        ":email"=> $email,
        ":password"=> $password,
        ":first_name"=> $first_name,
        ":last_name"=> $last_name));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function getUserData()
    {
        $this->_user = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;

        $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?');
        $query->execute(array($this->_user));
        return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function uploadPicture($uploaded)
    {
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    $targetPath .= "/wdv441/userLogin/app/views/img/";
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($uploaded['name']);
        $filesize = $uploaded['size'];
        $fileName = "profilePic". $this->_user . ".png";
        $ok = 1;
        $KB = 1024;
        $MB = 1048576;

        if ($filesize > 400*$KB)
        {
            echo "File too big.";
            $ok = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($uploaded['tmp_name'], $targetPath . $fileName))
            {
                echo "File " . $fileName . " has been uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "File not uploaded";
            } 
        }       
    }

    public function getPicture()
    {
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    $targetPath .= "/wdv441/userLogin/app/views/img/";
        $fileName = "profilePic". $this->_user . ".png";
        $image = null;

        if (file_exists($targetPath . $fileName))
        {
            $image = $fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            $image = "default.png";
        }
        return $image;
    }

}

?>
```

register.php:

```
<?php
require_once($loginClassPath);
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Error connecting to database. Error" . $e->getmessage;
    }

    if ($pdo)
    {
            $loginClass = new login($pdo);

            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $allFields = $_POST['first_name'] . $_POST['last_name'] . $_POST['email'] . $_POST['password'];

                if(!empty($allFields))
                {
                    if($loginClass->createUser($_POST['first_name'] , $_POST['last_name'] , $_POST['email'] , $_POST['password']))
                    {
                        if ($user_id = $loginClass->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) 
                        {
                            header('Location: myProfile.tpl.php');
                            die();
                        }
                    }
                }       
                else
                {
                    $errMsg = "red";
                }
            }

    }
}
else
{
    header('Location: myProfile.tpl.php');
    die();
}

?>
```

register.tpl.php:

```
<?php 
$errMsg=""; 

require_once($registerPath);
?>

<html>
<head>

<title>User login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> 
        <h3>Please Fill out all fields below: </h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>">

        <span style="color:<?php echo $errMsg; ?>;">All fields are required</span>
        <p>First Name: </p>
        <input type ="text" name="first_name" />
        <p>Last Name: </p>
        <input type ="text" name="last_name" />
        <p>Email: </p>
        <input type ="text" name="email" />
        <p>Password: </p>
        <input type="password" name ="password"/>
        <p><input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Register"/></p>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

login.tpl.php

```
<?php 
$errMsg=" "; 

require($loginPath);

?>

<html>
<head>

<title>User login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> 
        <h3>Please login below: </h3>
        <form method="post" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>>
            <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $errMsg ?></span>
            <p>Username: </p>
            <input type ="text" name="email" />
            <p>Password: </p>
            <input type="password" name ="password"/>
            <p><input type="submit" name ="login" value="Login"/></p>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.tpl.php">Register here</a>!</p>
        <form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently, when a new user registers, it kicks the user to the login screen. This is because when it redirects to "myProfile.php" I have the following code in the "myProfile.php" in order to make people sign in:

myProfile.php:

```
<?php           
require_once($loginClassPath);
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    try 
    {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error connecting to database. Error" . $e->getmessage;
    }
        if ($pdo)
        {
            $loginClass = new login($pdo);
            $userData = $loginClass->getUserData();

            if (isset($_GET['logout']))
            {
                if ($_GET['logout'] == 'yes')
                {
                    $loginClass->logout();
                    header('Location: login.tpl.php');
                    die();
                }
            }

        }
}
else
{
    header('Location: login.tpl.php');
    die();
}

?>
```

My question is basically where am I going wrong? Am I close or way off base here?

I apologize in advance if there is already a question similar to this, I looked around for a while but couldn't find anything that helped me. If I didn't supply enough info, please let me know!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what are the contents of the login.tpl.php file?

Comment: From what I see, it doesn't look like you specifically defined an actual class in the code, so `new login()` would throw an error unless you're not showing it?

Comment: I do have an entire class defined. I just abstracted the functions that were being used in the code snippets for the sake of making the question shorter. If you'd like me to add the entire class I can!

Comment: The full class is now in the question.

Comment: session_start needs to be the very first thing on the script, and it should exist on all pages where you are tracking the session. Try debuggin your last script there, try `if(!issset($_SESSION['user_id']) { echo "not set"; }`

Comment: Hi Rob, I added the following debugging code: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 { echo "not set"; } else { echo "set";}` and it comes back as set (but the session is empty)

Comment: I did also add session_start() to the top of all of my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I modified the class createUser function to do the following:

```
public function createUser($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password)
{
    $this->_email = $email;
    $this-> _password = $password;
    $this->hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');;
    $query->execute(array($this->_email));

    if ($query->rowcount() > 0)
    {
        echo "An account with that email already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name)");
        $query->execute(array(
        ":email"=> $email,
        ":password"=> $hash,
        ":first_name"=> $first_name,
        ":last_name"=> $last_name));
        $id = $this->_db->lastInsertId();

       $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
    }
}
```